# Calling the Google Maps API (Business)

Tags: api, google-maps, client

I'm stumped.
This should be fairly easy, but...
I bought a subscription for the Google Maps Engine for Business - and eventually managed to figure out how to generate a Client ID.
But however I try to call the Maps API, I keep getting the "not allowed" error message.
My script currently tries to fetch

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=[CLIENT_ID].apps.googleusercontent.com&sensor=false&v=3.4"></script>
```

I've tried removing the ".apps.googleusercontent.com" part.
Can anyone spot the error? Is there another way of testing the validity of your client id?
Thanks in advance.